# PyCharm can't find packages in project directory

Tags: pycharm

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers.logging'; 'helpers' is not a package`

But it's right there... (see screenshot)

The strange thing is that if I renamed the helpers package to "util" or anything else, it works. Why does the name of the package matter? Is this conflicting with something internal to PyCharm?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you have both a folder called helpers and a module called helpers.py. If you renamed the helpers folder to something like util, it works. But, if you renamed it to activities, I'll bet you run into the same problem.

Comment: This works (renamed the directory to _helpers), although its a mystery where this helpers.py module is coming from. Is there a helpers module in the Python Standard Library? Or maybe its something related to PyCharm?

Comment: It's a pretty common name. I see that Flask has a helpers.py file but I'm not sure that you would expect it in that directory, especially if you're not using Flask. As a bit of a hack, perhaps you could rename it to something else and run your programs and any tests you have. If everything runs fine, perhaps it's an artifact of some old experiment that you don't need. If something breaks, then you know you need it.